# Is there a way to display the URL bar for an external page in a windows Phone app made in Phonegap?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am building an app in Phonegap for windows phone 7, iOS and android using JQuery mobile.  The app was rejected by Microsoft because when it links to an external page to donate to a charity, the URL bar is not visible when the user goes to this external page to show the user that HTTPS is being used.  Is there a way to show the URL bar in the external page or to maybe force the link to open in Internet explorer.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use

```
target="_blank"
```

for external ulr?
Alternatively you can use the ChildBrowser Plugin.

Comment: I tried target="_blank" but it still opens the link in the in-app browser.  As for the ChildBrowser plugin I have been trying to use it but I can't get it to work.  Am I right in saying that the ChildBrowser.js goes in the www folder and the ChildBrowserCommand.cs goes into the plugins folder?

Comment: I never developed with phone gap in windows mobile ios there is a flag that enables the ability to open link in browser.

Comment: I think you can put ChildBrowserCommand.cs where you want.The important thing is that it is compiled with the application

Comment: I was unable to get the childbrowser plugin to work so in the end I had to get someone to put in some C# code into CordovaView.xaml.cs which made it work.